# Can I turn an vocal prase in a scream?

Tags: vocals, processing, screams

I have a soundpack of spoken vocals and I would like to use one of them as a scream. I'm not really intrested in keeping the chareteristics of the person who made the vocal but I just want them to scream it.

As of today I have no possibile way to record the scream myself but I have these spoken vocals. Is there a way to turn them into screams?

Answer (score 1):

You can add some compression to bring it forward and reverb for reflections - but changing the vocal characteristics of an audio requires recording another take or, alternatively,  layering and using effects like vocoding to the original samples - but results might not be as expected

Comment: So how should i go aboutthat with effects

Comment: You still need a good vocoder where you'll have to route the sounds so that both are going into the vocoder, so that the sample you have is being vocoded by the another shouted sample.

Vocoders are the effect daft punk uses for voices
https://youtu.be/vwf2uvWlL_c